# Set default value of dropdown from a Query Builder result list Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, query-builder

I am making an edit page of my form and I have a select dropdown but I need to set selected value for that coz it is an edit form. I am doing it like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $form = Form::find($id);
    $agent_options = array('' => 'Choose One') + DB::table('agents')->lists('name','id');
    $campaign_options = array('' => 'Choose One') + DB::table('campaigns')->lists('name','id');
    $query = "SELECT a.id, a.form_id, a.metrics_id, a.response, b.response as responseoption, b.metrics_name, b.description, b.question, a.remarks FROM qcv.forms_responses a INNER JOIN metrics b ON a.metrics_id = b.id WHERE form_id = $id;";
    $metric = DB::connection('mysql')->select($query);
    return view('form.edit')->with(array('form'=> $form, 'agent_options' => $agent_options, 'campaign_options' => $campaign_options, 'metric' => $metric));
}
```

In my View

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {!! Form::select('agent_id', $agent_options, '',array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'agent_id', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
</div>
```

Let's use my `$agent_options` dropdown, that will pull agents list in my agents table, but in my view how do I set a default value selected based on agent id? Let's say

`agend_id = 1`

is selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the default value to the `select()` as

```
{!! Form::select('agent_id', $agent_options, $defaultValue, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'agent_id', 'required' => 'required')) !!}}
```

replace the `$defaultValue` with the value you need to select by default.

refer the [DOC](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)